# Draw a rounded corner frame on all pages using tikz package

Tags: framed, ticks

I made a standard frame. It should appears on all pages of my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=0.1pt]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1.2cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.2cm,1.2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
(Type your content here.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make it rounded corner? 
To get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\draw` command has a `rounded corners` option which allows you to define the radius of the quarter circle. Here I used `1cm`, but adjust to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
%                      V-----------------V
\draw[line width=0.1pt,rounded corners=1cm]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (1.2cm,-1.2cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.2cm,1.2cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
(Type your content here.)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Phelype Oleinik. It works excellent for me. Thanks a lot!